# Resize a layout from its own class

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am creating a custom layout that subclasses a RelativeLayout.  I would like this to have fixed sizes, for example, a square would be 250x250, a rectangle would be 300x100, ect.  To achieve this I added a new xml attribute, type.  After seeing what type the layout will be, I would like to resize the layout.  I tried doing the following from my classes constructor:

```
switch(type)
{
   case SQUARE:
       setLayoutParams(new MyLayout.LayoutParams(250,250));
       break;
   case RECTANGLE:
       setLayoutParams(new MyLayout.LayoutParams(300,100));
       break;
}
```

This however did not override the height and width from the xml file.  Is there anyway to achieve what I would like to from my layout, or must dimension changes be made from the parent container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're overriding the width and height like that, you should override onMeasure, check what you are, and set the correct measurements by calling setMeasuredDimension() inside on onMeasure.